# Set dynamic intitial route in flutter with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i'm a newbie in flutter and firebase development and i have a question:
i have 2 routes: SignInRoute and HomeRoute, and when the app starts the user will be redirected to a screen depending on the currentUser.
if CurrentUser != null => redirect him to homeScreen else redirect to SignInScreen.
How can i add this logic to the main.dart.
Here is my code, when i run it always gives SignInScreen.routeName as initialRoute:

```
import 'package:books_library_app/routes.dart';
import 'package:books_library_app/theme.dart';
import 'package:books_library_app/ui/views/home/home_view.dart';
import 'package:books_library_app/ui/views/auth/sign_in_view.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  FirebaseUser user;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: theme(),
      initialRoute:
          (user != null) ? HomeView.routeName : SignInScreen.routeName,
      routes: routes,
    );
  }

  getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      user = currentUser;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to create a default landing page that checks if the user is logged in and forwards them along to the appropriate page afterward.

Comment: i tried this before, i created a Screen (statefullWidget) named Welcome and i set it as an initial route and in this widget i putted my logic but the probleme was that i couldn't navigate to a screen with a named route since in the Welcome screen must return a widget.

Comment: "Must return a widget"? What part of your logic needs to return a widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem may arises because of getting user function to be async so atfirst when your welcome page is built the initial value of user is null and when it get updated the widget is already built so one way you can do is to create welcome page as a loading screen or any splash screen of your app and in getcurrentuser function

```
 getCurrentUser() async {
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    if(currentuser==null){
//push to signin page
} 
else{
//push to home page
}
}
```

initstate function

```
 void initState() {
    getCurrentUser();
     super.initState();
  }
```

thanks i hope it will help let me know if you still face some issue

Comment: Thanks i will try and the tell and i have another questions
where can i call the getCurrentUser in the Loading Screen ?

Comment: your landing page is a loading screen from there in  initstate you will call this function and as soon this function get completed you will be navigated to either home or signin page i will update the answer with initstate function